# How do Chained IO Streams work in java

Tags: java, java-io, chaining

To be specific, If I chain as follows:

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferendInputStream(file));
```

What exactly happens under the hood? In the sense, how is the functionality of DataInputStream affected by chaining (What are added).

Please elaborate in more detail.

Comment: You should read about the _decorator_ design pattern.  Basically, wrapping one input stream inside another means that many things can happen, including adding new functionality to that stream.

Comment: "Please elaborate in more detail" sounds like an exam/homework question.